# When to use self and when to use retain

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, retain

am working my way through the "Beginning iPad Development" Apress book and have noticed that sometimes when the author is assigning values to a property they will use:

```
self.variable = value;
```

and other times, they will use:

```
variable = [value retain];
```

In both cases *variable* is a property defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) TYPE variable;
```

I wondered if anyone knew why this is done to help me better understand

Thanks,
 William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are often equivalent memory-wise. The compiler turns `self.variable = value` into `[self setVariable:value]` which then calls the generated setter (if you're using @synthesize) and retains it for you.

Comment: keep in mind though that you need to release the value if you retained it manually!

Comment: You need to release it manually if you use the retain attribute on a  property, too.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. A second question has came from this when the [value retain] statement is used is the retain being placed on the variable "value" or what it is pointing at?

Comment: @wibo In objective-C all objects are "pointed at". `[value retain]` retains the object, then returns it to you.

Comment: It only retains it if the property is defined as `(retain)`.

Answer (score 3):

One place where you use the second form is if you're defining your own setter method. You can't assign to self.variable there, because you'll call the setter recursively. So for example this is wrong:

```
-(void)setVariable:(TYPE*)value {
    if (value != variable) {
        [variable release];
        self.variable = [value retain]; // WRONG! Calls 
                                        // [self setVariable:[value retain]]
    }
}
```

This is right:

```
-(void)setVariable:(TYPE*)value {
    if (value != variable) {
        [variable release];
        variable = [value retain];
    }
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: This has a potential bug: if you call `obj.var = obj.var` you might release and deallocate the object before you retain it again.

Comment: thanks for the response I could see that being a nasty bug to track if it was in your code

Comment: cobbal: if you call `obj.val = ob.val` then `value != variable` will evaluate to false and the code inside the if block won't be called.

Comment: Ah, missed that for some reason. I can still think of a bizarre edge case bug in the case of arrays of arrays, although it might be more academic than anything `obj.var = [obj.var objectAtIndex:0]`